# Fixing RC4 cipher suites

Tags: linux, rhel, rc

I've conducted an AppScan on my web application, and it determined that the site uses weak cipher suites, as the AppScan successfully created SSL connections using each of the weak cipher suites listed here.

TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL Version: TLS 1.0
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL Version: TLS 1.0

The recommended solution is to 'change server's supported ciphersuites'

I'm using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 (Maipo).

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Read RedHat documentation on hardening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you a http server ... ngnix or apache running .

For apache you need to modify your ssl configuration by modifing the parameter ciphersuite

=> https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html

For nginx you need to modify the parameter ciphers

=> https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html

And if you server is a publc facing , you can test yourself the ssl part by running a test on https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/